# permalink to single page

Tags: permalinks, single

I have a certain post displayed and each post i click go to single page which shows more details of the post. But i have different templates for the post details which will be shown in single page.

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=posts&category_name=design'); while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Details</a>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

now in single.php I want to make a conditon where the_permalink could pass a slug maybe? then i could i include the template for design details.

Single.php

```
<?php get_header(); 

 $categorySlugName = single_cat_title(true);

if($categorySlugName == 'design'){

  include 'design-details.php';
}    

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty simple. after going through the wordpress codex,

just had to change the second line on single.php

```
$categorySlugName = single_cat_title(true);
```

TO

```
$cateogrySlugName = get_category_by_slug($slug);
```